# Work on a Wordpress Website on multiple computers

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if copying the C:\wamp\www\mysite folder on usb key could work on my computer ?

Thanks Guys

i've never tried yet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Drag and drop of WAMP data may work, if you also copy MySQL. Find the path where WAMP stores databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to have the same (or near same) development environment setup on the computer you are transferring the folder to...
Maybe if you are using Apache and SQL and such. They would have to be on the other computer.
Another thing to consider is uploading your project online and using Git to develop. That way any work you do on one computer could be updated to the Git repository, and that would save you running back and forth with a usb key to keep the project up to date on multiple computers.